# Obtener substring en SQL que tiene un patrón definido

Tags: sql-server

Lo que deseo es obtener una parte de una cadena de texto que esta entre unos pipes (|) esta expresión contiene números y comas, ¿alguien tiene alguna sugerencia de cómo hacerlo?

tengo estos ejemplos:
|5|61|363|SP-105|1000|KM|49|TNS|2.23|REN|449.089|LTR|1|FP|**1348,1360**|
(quiero obtener **1348,1360**

|18|66|410|SP-105|1804|KM|50|TNS|2.65|REN|681.8512|LTR|1.65|FP|**1504,1526**|
(quiero obtener **1504,1526**

|12-22|5-Ago-2021|SP-106 |**857,868,869,870**|5|tlaj-vcrz-xala-mx-gdl |2139KM |79990KG
(quiero obtener **857,868,869,870**

Comment: Si la respuesta resolvió tu escenario, considera en marcarla como aceptada, de este modo colaboramos para mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iniciando variables

```
DECLARE @TextoParaRevisar1 VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TextoParaRevisar2 VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TextoParaRevisar3 VARCHAR(MAX);
```

Asignando los valores

```
SET @TextoParaRevisar1 = '|5|61|363|SP-105|1000|KM|49|TNS|2.23|REN|449.089|LTR|1|FP|1348,1360|';
SET @TextoParaRevisar2 = '|12-22|5-Ago-2021|SP-106 |857,868,869,870|5|tlaj-vcrz-xala-mx-gdl |2139KM |79990KG'
SET @TextoParaRevisar3 = '|18|66|410|SP-105|1804|KM|50|TNS|2.65|REN|681.8512|LTR|1.65|FP|1504,1526|';
```

Texto 1

```
SELECT Value as 'Extraido de TextoParaRevisar1'
FROM string_split(@TextoParaRevisar, '|')
WHERE Value like '%[0-9],[0-9]%'
```

Resultado

```
Extraido de TextoParaRevisar1
1348,1360
```

Texto 2

```
SELECT Value  as 'Extraido de TextoParaRevisar2'
FROM string_split(@TextoParaRevisar2, '|')
WHERE Value like '%[0-9],[0-9]%'
```

Resultado

```
Extraido de TextoParaRevisar2
857,868,869,870
```

Texto 3

```
SELECT Value  as 'Extraido de TextoParaRevisar3'
FROM string_split(@TextoParaRevisar3, '|')
WHERE Value like '%[0-9],[0-9]%'
```

Resultado

```
Extraido de TextoParaRevisar3
1504,1526
```

¿Y si los valores están dentro de una tabla?

Bueno, he creado una tabla simple: ID y Texto, la tabla se llama `StackOverflowES_532081`

```
SELECT Texto 
FROM StackOverflowES_532081
```

Resultado

```
Texto
|5|61|363|SP-105|1000|KM|49|TNS|2.23|REN|449.089|LTR|1|FP|1348,1360|
|12-22|5-Ago-2021|SP-106 |857,868,869,870|5|tlaj-vcrz-xala-mx-gdl |2139KM |79990KG
|18|66|410|SP-105|1804|KM|50|TNS|2.65|REN|681.8512|LTR|1.65|FP|1504,1526|
```

¿Cómo le hago para obtener solamente los valores numéricos que tengan comas decimales?

```
SELECT Value Texto -- Para entender el por qué el uso de Value, revisar la documentación.
FROM StackOverflowES_532081
CROSS APPLY string_split(Texto, '|')
WHERE Value like '%[0-9],[0-9]%'
```

Resultado

```
Texto
1348,1360
857,868,869,870
1504,1526
```

Referencias:

Documentación SQL Server: [STRING_SPLIT (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Preferiría una condición como `WHERE Value NOT like '%[^0-9,]%'`. Eso permite que solo haya números y comas para evitar falsos positivos.

Comment: Vale, gracias por el detalle :D